# how to solve these errors :[ModelDatabase.cc:290]

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

when I run gazebo, the errors appear:

1\Error [ModelDatabase.cc:290] Unable to parse manifest.xml for model[http://gazebosim.org/models/double_pendulum_with_base]
2\ Error [ModelDatabase.cc:290] Unable to parse manifest.xml for model[http://gazebosim.org/models/kitchen_dining]
3\ gazebo: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::common::NumericAnimation]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

why appear these? how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1509/how-to-solve-these-errors-:%5Bmodeldatabase.cc:290%5D/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-26**:
I just filled a ticket for this issue: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/537/manifest-error-in-gazebosimorg-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`manifest.xml` files are being deprecated, and replaced with `model.config`. We are doing this to remove naming conflicts with ROS. New models in the database will not have `manifest.xml` files. So the solution to your problem is to upgrade Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-08**:
Am I assuming right that the update to 1.5 for ROS Groovy users will solve this issue?